# SQL to Hive query syntax

Tags: hive

How can I turn the below SQL to Hive query? I get an error `FAILED: ParseException line 2:31 cannot recognize input near 'select' 't2' '.' in expression specification`

```
select ip,
       sum(case when score <> (select t2.score from score t2
                               where t2.timestamp = (select max(timestamp) from score
                                                     where ip = t2.ip
                                                       and timestamp < t1.timestamp)
                                 and t1.ip = t2.ip) then 1 else 0 end)
from score t1
group by ip;
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the input table and ouput?  I think u can do this with an `OVER` clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive does not support subqueries in case statements AFAIK.  You could restructure this to an outer query (atill using case) from an inline view.

```
select ip, sum(case when score <> s.score) ..
from (select  t2.score ..) s
```

Comment: can you elaborate / show me the restructured query?

Comment: Sorry I have sprained wrist and can type little. Will do what I can.